# Iterate through workbooks and worksheets Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use Openpyxl to iterate through some excel workbooks and all the sheets contained within those workbooks. I'm not getting and error, but the second part of my code starting with loading the YK-2022.xlsx is not working. The YK-2022.xlsx file is not updating with the information that I want. Anyone know why this might be?

I assume you are not able to load multiple workbooks using a string like wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Molina.xlsx', 'YK-2022.xlsx'). I have several files that I need to update with the same information and am trying to figure out the most efficient way to do so. I'm fairly new to Openpyxl and Python. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Molina.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)

for worksheets in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[worksheets]
    print(worksheet)
sheet_ranges = wb.worksheets
sheet = wb.active
sheet["B15"] = "October 1, 2021"
sheet["B16"] = "October 1, 2022"
sheet["B43"] = " "
sheet["A41"] = "Period 10/1/2022-10/1/2023"
wb.save(filename="Molina.xlsx")

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'YK-2022.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)

for worksheets in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[worksheets]
    print(worksheet)
    
sheet_ranges = wb.worksheets
print(wb.sheetnames)
sheet["B15"] = "October 1, 2023"
sheet["B16"] = "October 1, 2024"
sheet["B43"] = " "
sheet["A41"] = "Period 10/1/2022-10/1/2023"
sheet["B50"] = "John Doe"
wb.save(filename="YK-2022.xlsx")
```

Comment: Don't you miss the activation of the workbook in the second part (I take it the first part works)? You have "sheet = wb.active" in the first part after "sheet_ranges = wb.worksheets", but you are missing it in the second part.
If you have multiple files - create list and loop through them.

Comment: I think I left that out because I was playing with the code to figure out why it wasn't working. I added it back in and it is still not working. I can't seem to figure out to create the list to loop through the files and I don't want to have to duplicate this code over and over again for each workbook file.

Comment: For me it is actually working with added "sheet = wb.active". Do you get any error?

Comment: No error code. It works on the last sheet that was open but I want it to iterate through all the sheets in the workbook.

Comment: Oh, you have multiple sheets also? Well you're not looping through them in the code (there is no indentation).

Comment: Thanks for your help! For some reason this only updates the excel sheet that was last selected when I save and close the file. It still won't iterate through all the sheets in the workbook. Strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243198/discussion-between-baby-yoda-and-misa-charvatova).

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop - first through list of files, secondly through the list of sheets:

```
from fileinput import filename
from openpyxl import load_workbook

list_of_files = ["abc", "def"]

for file in list_of_files:
    file_name = f"{file}.xlsx"
    wb = load_workbook(filename=file_name)
    for worksheets in wb.sheetnames:
        print(worksheets)
        sheet = wb[worksheets]
        sheet["B15"] = "October 1, 2021"
        sheet["B16"] = "October 1, 2022"
        sheet["B43"] = " "
        sheet["A41"] = "Period 10/1/2022-10/1/2023"
        wb.save(filename=file_name)
```